# Crystal reports Sum if a previous field is the same to current field on section 3(details)

Tags: sum, suppression

Hi im just a newbie programmer and I have a problem in my crystal reports.

I have a table named "payroll" and has this fields(ID,FullName,NetSalary)
I have inserted 3 records on my mysql table:

```
ID|FullName|Netsalary
1 |Cris Tiu|500
2 |Mat Joe |100
3 |Mat Joe |400
```

how can I make it Look like this?
I dont want to Group them by Fullname and give a total but instead if the full name is duplicated, It will Display it once and total the Net salary.

```
ID|FullName|Netsalary
1 |Cris Tiu|500
2 |Mat Joe |500
```

I have tried adding a formula that contained this code:

```
if {Fulname}=previous({Fullname}) then
Sum({Netsalary})
else
{Netsalary}
```

but it gives me a display like this:

```
ID|FullName|Netsalary
1 |Cris Tiu|"Blank"
2 |Mat Joe |100
3 |Mat Joe |500
```

Please Help me my work depends on this. Thank You in Advance

Comment: I finally got the answer to my question by trying things my self.

Comment: I finally got the answer to my question by trying things myself. I just Grouped it by "Fullname" and Summed it. Then Suppressed the groupheader and the groupfooter. Then created a formula and inserted the sum from groupfooter and placed the formula to my details section hope this will help others